# Need help troubleshooting a shell script that won't launch (yes, permissions are 755)

Tags: osx-server, launchd, script

It could be the lateness of the hour, but I can't understand why the following script isn't working. It's directly from the CommuniGate Pro documentation http://www.communigate.com/CGPSophos/#Update, but when I try to run it manually, the echo commands don't echo, and the email never gets sent.

Installation process: copy from web page, sudo pico filename, paste, save, chmod 755.

Everything works fine when I run the commands it calls directly; the problem there is that I want to have these regularly launched by launchd, and the commands only work if they're run as ./commandname from that base directory—<s>no idea how to do that in launchd and Apple docs not helping. (Question will be considered answered if someone tells me how to do this.)</s> [Edit: found the WorkingDirectory key in "man launchd.plist", but help on the shell script thing would still be nifty.]

The script:

```
#!/bin/sh
SOPHOS_PATH="/var/CommuniGate/CGPSophos"
MAILER_CMD="/usr/bin/mail -s 'Sophos Update Report'"
REPORT_ADR="postmaster"
( \
if [ "$1" = -m ]; then
 echo "Launching Sophos monthly update..."
 cd ${SOPHOS_PATH}
 ./monthlyUpdate 2>&1
 ./engineUpdate 2>&1
fi
echo "Launching Sophos daily update..."
  cd ${SOPHOS_PATH}
  ./dailyUpdate 2>&1
) | eval ${MAILER_CMD} ${REPORT_ADR}
```

Comment: Ah... found the WorkingDirectory key in the launchd.plist man page. One problem solved. Would still like to know why the shell script is borked.

Comment: I'm confused. You mention that it doesn't work if you run it manually, but you also mention that it does work if you run ./command. And launchd seems to play a role as well (which opens another can of worms). Can we take this step by step and focus on getting the script to run in a shell to start with? Could you rewrite your question accordingly?

Comment: The echo don't show in Terminal as there output is sent to mail. Is your mail server configured correctly? Can you replace the `eval ${MAILER_CMD} ${REPORT_ADR}` part with `cat` to get everything dumped on screen?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I'm still editing my question and you're here already. Yes, the problem is that /path/to/script.sh returns a system prompt after maybe a half-second; even if the rest of the commands are problematic, since it's not getting to the echo commands, I'm assuming nothing is happening. ./monthlyUpdate works; ./script.sh does not.

Comment: Aha (re "output sent to mail")! Got it, I didn't realize that echo was also being redirected. Yes, entirely possible there's a mail problem, this is a dev server and I haven't tested outbound mail yet. Give me a minute, I'll remove the eval code and try again—that should put it on stdout, right?

Comment: stdout, correct

Comment: Yep, you got it perfectly. The problem wasn't the script, it was the lack of feedback. Script works fine without the mail redirect, which I can fix when we install it on the primary server. Thanks!

Comment: I'll leave it to you to put that in as an answer, or should I note this answered and "see comments"?

Comment: If you want to make this a good answer, please document the steps you took to analyse the problem and solve it (aka check whether all paths exist/are accessible, whether the output with `cat` is correct etc). This will at least provide *some* value for whoever runs into a similar problem in the future.

Comment: Okay, will do. My launchd plists aren't working yet; I'll debug those and update this page when I figure out what's wrong.